# Child view in Expandable list view get Shrinks automatically to wrap content, Even though I mentioned the View to match parent

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

**EarBoxExpandableListAdapter**

```
public class EarBoxExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

public EarBoxExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                   HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.childrow, null);
    }

//        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
//                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
//
//        txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.parentrow, null);
    }



    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
}
```

Below is my xml layout code for the child row.Evwnthough I kept the width as match parent, in actual output which I attached as screen shot Im getting the wrap content of the child rows.

**childrow.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/round_corner_rect"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/songCurrentDurationLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#747272"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:text="3.25"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/songProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="6dp"
            android:paddingRight="6dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/songTotalDurationLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#656262"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:text="42:52"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <Button
            style="@style/earBoxbuttonStyle"
            android:text="Save"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" />

        <Button
            style="@style/earBoxbuttonStyle"
            android:text="Reply"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" />

        <Button
            style="@style/earBoxbuttonStyle"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

**MessageInboxFragment**

```
/**
 * Created by sethu on 6/13/2016.
 */
public class MessageInboxFragment extends Fragment{
    ExpandableListView expandableListView;
    EarBoxExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
     static List<String> listDataHeader;
     static HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
    private int lastExpandedPosition = -1;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages_inbox, container, false);
        expandableListView=(ExpandableListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
        expandableListView.setDividerHeight(1);
//        final ArrayList<Parent> dummyList = ExpandableListMain.buildDummyData();
        prepareListData();
        listAdapter = new EarBoxExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);
        expandableListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                if (lastExpandedPosition != -1
                        && groupPosition != lastExpandedPosition) {
                    expandableListView.collapseGroup(lastExpandedPosition);
                }
                lastExpandedPosition = groupPosition;
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    public static void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("Top 250");
        listDataHeader.add("Now Showing");
        listDataHeader.add("Coming Soon..");

        // Adding child data
        List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
        top250.add("The Shawshank Redemption");

        List<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
        nowShowing.add("The Conjuring");

        List<String> comingSoon = new ArrayList<String>();
        comingSoon.add("2 Guns");

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), nowShowing);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), comingSoon);
    }


}
```

**[xml screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmVoN.png)**

[device output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V10YS.png)

Comment: Did you fix your problem?

Comment: yes fixed it. It was the row xml file which cause this issue.